# Office 365 site not opening in IE & also not connecting from visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2012-r2, ie

**ISSUE 1:** My Office 365 SharePoint site is not opening in IE. IE asking for credentials after entering the URL but nothing happening after providing credentials. below is the screen shot.

[image]

**ISSUE 2:** I am going to create "SharePoint App" in visual studio 2015. Visual studio asking for Site URL & credentials. but after providing the credentials screen remains blank. nothing happening. see below screenshot.

[image]

**NOTE:**

1. Site is added in trusted sites in IE.
2. JavaScript is enabled in IE.
3. site is opening in chrome and firefox. only problem is in IE.
4. Other internet sites are opening fine in IE. only sharepoint site is not opening.

**Below is my system details**

1. Windows server 2012 standard
2. Visual studio 2015
3. IE 10.0.92
4. Office Professional Plus 2013

Please help.

Comment: Has the site been responding/loading previously, but just suddenly doesn't work, or is this a new & never accessed site?

Comment: This is the new site i have created today. Its first time i am going to open in IE.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Anew vm with IE10 on Windows Server 2012. Any ideas? It works in Chrome however when I try to deploy from visual studio to my sharepoint online developer site it doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- [Delete InternetExplorer Browser Cache](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141)
- Maybe your IE Security-Zones have been modified. [Try resetting them to their defaults](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-internet-explorer-security-settings-to-default-levels-2624499)
- Try [turning off all IE Add-Ons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17447/windows-internet-explorer-11-manage-add-ons)
- Press F12 in IE to open [Developer-Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx) for more troubleshooting. Maybe also [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) will help you to get more information about the problem

Comment: I tried all above. but nothing helps

Comment: Did you try opening the site on another Computer with InternetExplorer? Would be interesting to know if it's a client-problem or a page-problem.

Comment: Yeah! It's opening on other computer.

Comment: Can you log in with another user account on the same server? This helps us isolate the error (server-wide problem or problem in the user-profile of the logged in account).

Comment: tried with another user. but no luck.